# references for algebraic topology of (complex) manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Now I want to study some fundamental theorems of cohomology of (complex) manifolds.
e.g., Poincare duality, Kunneth formula, weak and hard Lefschetz, cup product, cycle maps, "de Rham cohomology = singular cohomology = derived sheaf cohomology = Cech cohomology", and so on.
I'm reading Bott-Tu's "differential forms in algebraic topology", so I know some of these for De Rham cohomology.
I want to know these theorems for integers coefficient cohomology.

Glancing through the table of contents, it seems that the chapter 0 of Griffiths-Harris contains all of these (for complex manifolds).
But many people say that it is too brief for the people who study it first time.
(I've read Hartshorne, so I think it may be readable for me...)

So please suggest to me some references.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried Claire Voisin's book "Hodge theory and complex geometry" I & II ?

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Thank you very much! I'll borrow and try it.